# c strtok returns NULL after return from recursion

Tags: c, recursion, strtok

When i'm not calling the same function in my code everything works well but when the function returns from a recursion suddenly the variable `pch` is NULL:

```
 void someFunction()
     {
        char * pch;
        char tempDependencies[100*64+100];
        strcpy(tempDependencies,map[j].filesNeeded);
        pch = strtok(tempDependencies,",");
        while (pch != NULL)
        {
            someFunction(); <- if i comment this out it works fine
            pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }
      }
```

So for instance when the loop acts on the string `file2,file3,file4` it correctly split `file2` and modifies the string to `file2\\000file3,file4` but the next call to `pch = strtok (NULL, ",");` renders `pch` to be `0x0`. Are there things that i'm not aware of when calling recursion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`strtok()` is not reentrant. If you want use it in a recursive function you must use `strtok_r()`.

See also: [strtok, strtok_r](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r)

Answer (score 5):

You can't call the `strtok` function again before the previous execution is done - It is not [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29).

Use its reentrant version `strtok_r` instead.